# add product from one domain, to the cart of different domain(both are on same server)

Tags: php, session, cart

i have two domains say abc.com and xyz.com both are on same server, abc.com is core php based shopping cart developed to sell my company product

now abc.com is main doamin and xyz.com has been created for special marketing of specific product

now,(what i want) if someone clicks on any product on xyz.com i want to redirect it to abc.com/cart.html( i know about redirection from one domain to another) where it will show product selected by user on xyz.com added to cart.

xyz.com has a single page showing three products .

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is that both domains have to store the sessions at the same place.

Then you have to make the client use the same session id on both domains, to do that, pass the session id in all links and redirects that go from one domain to another.

```
<a href="http://xyz.com/cart.php?<?php echo SID ?>">cart</a>
```

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: php doesn't really care where the session originated, as long as it finds the session id and then finds the session file (or other storage you use), it will use it. So you have to make sure 2 things are in place:
1. the storage is the same, with same session ids
2. the session id propagates acros the two sites